# # Flutter Adding Two Fields Result

Tags: flutter

I have created a List that stores and save multiple values and then sum it.
Now I have created another text field that stores price I wanna multiple this text field value with the list result but getting error it display null please help me out thankyou.

```
This is the code How I am doing sum of List 

 List<String> items = <String>[];
     int getTotal() {
    return items.fold(0, (total, item) {
      int? price = int.tryParse(item);
      if (price != null) {
        num = total + price;
        return (num);
        // return total + price;
      } else {
        return total;
      }
    });
  }
```

---

List

---

```
 Column(
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    items.length,
                    (index) => TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      onChanged: (value) => items[index] = value,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: items[index],
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
                          onPressed: () {
                            items.remove(items[index]);
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

---

Then I am creating another field where I am getting price

```
This is how I am creating another text field which value I wanna multiply with the above list value.

       Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      autofocus: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Total Price: ',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        errorStyle:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                      controller: amountController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please Enter Price';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: If you start at 0, and use that value to do `total * num`, won't you always get a value of 0 from that?

Comment: Haven't got your point please elaborate

Comment: I think you updated it, but I was just saying `total` started out at 0. So every time you do `total * num` the result is 0, which means the end result would always be 0. The new solution looks better

Answer (score 2):

This is how should your **sum function** should looks like:

```
int getMultiply() {
  return multiply.fold(0, (int total, element) {
    final price = int.tryParse(element);
    // if price can't be parsed returns total
    return total + (price ?? 0);
  });
 }
```

This is an example of **text field's controller** that updates global state every time it's value can be parsed to int and not equals to 0:

```
final TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController()
..addListener(() {
  final value = int.tryParse(amountController.text) ?? 0;
  final result = value * getMultiply();
  if (result > 0) {
    setState(() {
      // some global field that presents requested value
      multiplyResult = result;
    });
  }
});
```

List of items:

```
Column(children: [
  ...List.generate(
    items.length,
    (index) => TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() { items[index] = value; }),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: items[index],
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
              items.remove(items[index]);
            }),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Please check the updated one thanks on the basis of that please update your solution